# Просмотр изменений на удаленном репозитории

Tags: git

Можно ли с локального рабочего места посмотреть:

1. Были ли изменения в удаленном репозитории
2. Какие это были изменения

Чтобы принять решение - вливать-не вливать и что вливать?

---

нашел решение для просмотра изменений diff после fetch

```
git diff HEAD...origin/master
git diff HEAD...origin/branch1
```

насколько оно правомочно?
вывод вполне наглядный
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: всегда можно сделать просто git fetch и посмотреть у себя локально. Оно мержиться не будет.

Comment: Простого [`git log`](https://githowto.com/ru/history) достаточно?

Comment: @KoVadim сделал фетч, не мёржил, но git diff ничего не показал - вообще никакого вывода в терминале... хотя на удаленном репо - изменения сделаны...
как так, что делаю неправильно?

Comment: как Вы уже написали - `git diff master...origin/master` и тому подобное

Answer (score 10, accepted):

команда *pull* программы *git* на самом деле является последовательностью двух команд: *fetch* и *merge*.

*fetch* — получает обновившиеся указатели (т.е., ветки — branch, и метки — tag) и скачивает все необходимые для их (указателей) использования объекты (т.е., коммиты — commit, деревья — tree и «блобы» — blob, binary large object).

*merge указатель* — пытается осуществить «вливание» коммита (и всех промежутоных коммитов), на который ссылается *указатель*, в вашу текущую ветку (ветка в *git* — это плавающий указатель на коммит).

выполнив не *pull*, а только первую часть — *fetch*:

```
$ git fetch
```

вы получите возможность просмотреть, какие коммиты сейчас отделяют ваш локальный указатель (например, ветку *master*) от другого указателя, полученного из удалённого репозитория (если репозиторий подключен всего один, то называется по умолчанию — *origin*), например, одноимённой ветки *master*, которую можно обозначить как `origin/master`:

```
$ git log master..origin/master
```

две точки здесь — это часть синтаксиса.

какие именно произошли изменения и в каких файлах, можно увидеть, добавив команде *log* опцию `-p`:

```
$ git log -p master..origin/master
```

а можно посмотреть и полный список отличий в файлах между двумя указателями:

```
$ git diff master..origin/master
```

---

> нашел решение для просмотра изменений diff после fetch
>   `git diff HEAD...origin/master`
>   насколько оно правомочно?

вполне правомочно.

и полностью соответствует выводу `git diff master..origin/master`, если *master* — ваша текущая ветка. уточнить вы можете с помощью команды `git status`, или более «низкоуровнево», заглянув в содержимое файла `.git/HEAD`. пример:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
```

здесь указатель *HEAD* ссылается именно на локальную ветку *master*.

Comment: круто! спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Comment: а мержить как правильно?
если мне, например, надо взять только одно имзенение

Comment: @buyboy, это уже совсем другой вопрос, который здесь, насколько помню, не раз уже встречался.

Comment: @buyboy, раз git Вам нужен не только для `add/commit/push/pull`, чтобы каждый раз не спрашивать, почитайте руководства по его использованию. [**Это**](https://githowto.com/ru) короткое, написано понятным языком, а в [**данном**](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/) больше материала и подробностей. Где непонятно, застопоритесь — обращайтесь сюда.

Comment: @alexander barakin круть! мегаспасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Если всё правильно понял, Вам нужна команда `git log`. Если не вводить никаких дополнительных параметров, выведутся хэш коммита, его автор, дата и описание:

```
$ git log
commit fa3c1411aa09441695a9e645d4371e8d749da1dc
Author: Alexander Shvets <alex@githowto.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 9 10:27:54 2011 -0500

    Added HTML header

commit 8c3228730ed03116815a5cc682e8105e7d981928
Author: Alexander Shvets <alex@githowto.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 9 10:27:54 2011 -0500

    Added standard HTML page tags

commit 43628f779cb333dd30d78186499f93638107f70b
Author: Alexander Shvets <alex@githowto.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 9 10:27:54 2011 -0500

    Added h1 tag

commit 911e8c91caeab8d30ad16d56746cbd6eef72dc4c
Author: Alexander Shvets <alex@githowto.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 9 10:27:54 2011 -0500

    First Commit
```

О команде и параметрах расписано [**здесь**](https://githowto.com/ru/history).

Если под «какие это были изменения» понимается содержание изменений, для просмотра диффов необходим параметр `-p`. Также можно указать количество последних коммитов, чьё содержание нам необходимо просмотреть.

В примере ниже помимо дефолтных параметров команды `git log`, выведутся разница изменений — `-p` — двух последних коммитов — `-2`.

```
$ git log -p -2
commit ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949
Author: Scott Chacon <schacon@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 17 21:52:11 2008 -0700

    changed the version number

diff --git a/Rakefile b/Rakefile
index a874b73..8f94139 100644
--- a/Rakefile
+++ b/Rakefile
@@ -5,5 +5,5 @@ require 'rake/gempackagetask'
 spec = Gem::Specification.new do |s|
     s.name      =   "simplegit"
-    s.version   =   "0.1.0"
+    s.version   =   "0.1.1"
     s.author    =   "Scott Chacon"
     s.email     =   "schacon@gee-mail.com

commit 085bb3bcb608e1e8451d4b2432f8ecbe6306e7e7
Author: Scott Chacon <schacon@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Sat Mar 15 16:40:33 2008 -0700

    removed unnecessary test code

diff --git a/lib/simplegit.rb b/lib/simplegit.rb
index a0a60ae..47c6340 100644
--- a/lib/simplegit.rb
+++ b/lib/simplegit.rb
@@ -18,8 +18,3 @@ class SimpleGit
     end

 end
-
-if $0 == __FILE__
-  git = SimpleGit.new
-  puts git.show
-end
\ No newline at end of file
```

Подробно о дополнительных опциях [**тут**](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Comment: козырно... сначала посмотреть коротенько, а потом отобразить нужное... большой респект за ответ!

Comment: кстати, эти хэши используются в git cherry-pick для присоединения?

Comment: @buyboy, да, см. https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-Git-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0#%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA

Comment: @buyboy, если какой-то ответ помог в решении Вашей проблемы, поставьте, пожалуйста, рядом с ним галочку. Это покажет другим участникам, что вопрос решён, а Вам добавится дополнительные 2 балла репутации.

Comment: хорошо, я уже поставил